# Primefaces. Use ajax validation before downloading file

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces, download

In one of my applications I have several buttons that makes the following:
a) Send a non-ajax call to download a File
b) Server makes some validations
c) If validations are passed, then file is generated and downloaded
d) If validations fail, then an error message is shown.

The button might look like this (I don't use p:fileDownload because it is an inherited project, but I could use it if needed)

```
        <p:commandLink styleClass="btn" id="botonExcel"
            title="#{text['label.generar.excel']}"
            action="#{incidenciasCuentasPagosAction.descargaExcelSeguimiento}" update=":messages" ajax="false"
            rendered="#{not empty incidenciasCuentasPagosAction.existenIncidencias}">
            <span class="hab-icon-24 hab-icon-excel"></span>
            <span class="hab-button-text">#{text['label.generar.excel']}</span>
        </p:commandLink>
```

It works ok, but I have a problem. As the call is non-ajax, the whole page is reloaded, which is a bit annoying. For example, it moves to the top of the page.

What do I want to do:

1. Make an AJAX call to validate an generate de File
2. If there is an error, show message
3. If everything works, make a non AJAX call to donwload de File

The problem is that I don't know how to trigger a non-AJAX call after validation is passed. I know how to make an AJAX call with <p:remoteCommand>, but it only allows AJAX. The only workaround I know is to use a hidden button and click on it, but I find it a hack, so I'd prefer another solution.

Comment: From my experience in case where is validation before stream I use two buttons. One button is with ajax that contains server validation with validation status message. Other button is  non ajax button that just do file stream. Then if validations are ok first button calls javascript click on second button, if validation is failed than doesnt do nothing. So you just need to call javscript click on second button if validation is ok.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a servlet to serve the download. This will leave you with sending a JavaScript location change in your bean action:

```
if (success) {
  PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.location.href = 'SERVLET_URI'");
}
else {
  // Set error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax button checks valdiations in bean and if everything is ok starts remote command that fires javascript click function that clicks non ajax button that is hidden. If validation fails it won't do anything. I've only managed to do it this way and it is working for me.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rC" onstart="clickMe()" autoRun="false" process="@this"/>
<p:commandButton value="Ajax" actionListener="#{yourBean.checkForValidations}" process="@this"/>
<p:commandButton value="NON - Ajax" ajax="false" id="nonAjaxBtn" style="visibility: hidden;">
<p:fileDownload value="#{yourBean.print()}"/>
</p:commandButton>

function clickMe()
{
var f = document.getElementById("formName:nonAjaxBtn");
f.click();
}

public void checkForValidations()
{
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("rC();");
}
```